# How to get referer url without the id?

Tags: php

I use this code to get referer url:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

And the output is:

> http://example.com/application/view/viewleave.php?idleave=1

How should i do to get this?

> http://example.com/application/view/viewleave.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could lop off everything after the `?` character.

```
$text = "http://example.com/application/view/viewleave.php?idleave=1";
$output = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,'?'));
echo $output;
```

edit: Like someone else said, if the string doesn't contain '?', then $output will be empty. So you could check for that first using strrpos()

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/application/view/viewleave.php?idleave=1');
```

and you'll get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /application/view/viewleave.php
    [query] => idleave=1
)
```

and merge.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the string for a '?' character.  If it exists take the substring before it, else take the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],0,strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
str_replace('?'.parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help. I got it solve after reading your reply.

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$pos = strpos($referer, '?');
if ($pos !== false) {
$output = substr($referer,0,strrpos($referer,'?'));
}
else
{
$output = $referer;
}
echo $output;
?>
```